# Is there any way to align a line chart with a grouped column chart in charts.js?

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js

I have a column chart with 2 different data sets. This results in 2 columns for each cell. The issue arises when I want to draw a line chart on the same graph of which the data aligns with the columns, so I would need 2 points on the line in the same cell. Unfortunately it seems like Charts.js can only draw lines with 1 point for each cell. This results in something like this:

Here's an example of the graph: https://i.imgur.com/jh3sV3D.png

Is there any way to draw that line chart so the data-points align correctly with the columns?

```
   type:"bar",
   data:{  
      "labels":[  
         "Team LQC1",
         "Team LQC5",
         "Team PRIO",
         "Team LQC9",
         "Team LQC2"
      ],
      datasets:[  
         {  
            type:"line",
            label:"Id",
            borderColor:"#ffa600",
            backgroundColor:"none",
            pointBackgroundColor:"#ffa600",
            fill:"none",
            data:[  
               1,
               7,
               2,
               8,
               3,
               9,
               4,
               10,
               5,
               11
            ]
         },
         {  
            data:[  
               1,
               2,
               3,
               4,
               5
            ],
            label:"This Week",
            backgroundColor:"#003f5c"
         },
         {  
            data:[  
               7,
               8,
               9,
               10,
               11
            ],
            label:"Previous Week",
            backgroundColor:"#7a5195"
         }
      ]
   },
   options:{  
      elements:{  
         line:{  
            tension: 0 // disables bezier curves
         },

      },
      maintainAspectRatio:false,
      responsive:true,
      legend:{  
         display:false,

      },
      scales:{  
         yAxes:[  
            {  
               scaleLabel:{  
                  display:true,
                  labelString:"Id",

               },
               ticks:{  
                  beginAtZero:true,

               },

            },

         ],

      },

   }
```